# Finding the corresponding date of one data.frame within another data.frame (data.table)

Tags: r, date, data.table, comparison

As this is my first question on stackoverflow, I hope that it meets all requirements. Down below, You've got the reproducible example. Two data.tables with monthly data and one data.table which provides corresponding dates.

First, I wanted to check, if the Dates of dt_list1 and dt_list2 are in the timeframe (variable: Within.period) of the corresponding date values of dt_dates_melted.

Problem is here, that there are several conditions, which the comparison has to fulfill:

- If it is >Store< 1 or 2, it should check if >Date< is within the timeframe of >dates< for >Store< 1 or 2.
- If it is >Store< 3, it should check if >Date< is within the timeframe of >dates< for >Region< C and >City< 1.
- If it is >Region< C AND >Interviewer< 1, it should check if >Date< is within the timeframe of >dates< for >Region< B.
- If it is >Region< C AND >Interviewer< 2 or 3, it should check if >Date< is within the timeframe of >dates< for >Region< C and >City< 0.
- For the Rest of >Region< C, it should check if >Date< is within the timeframe of >dates< for >Region< C and >City< 1.
- For the remaining >Regions< A and B, it should check, if >Date< is within the timeframe of >dates< for >Regions< A and B.

```
library(data.table)

list1 <- data.table(
  Month = rep(1, 500), 
  Region = sample(c("A", "B", "C"), 500, replace = T, prob = c(0.25, 0.25, 0.5)),
  Store = sample(seq(1:7), 500, replace = T), 
  Interviewer = sample(seq(1:9), 500, replace = T),
  Sale = sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), 500, replace = T, prob = c(0.25, 0.75)),
  Date = sample(seq(as.Date('2020/01/01'), as.Date('2020/01/13'), by="day"), 500, replace = T),
  Day = NA,
  Within.Period = NA,
)

list2 <- data.table(
  Month = rep(2, 600), 
  Region = sample(c("A", "B", "C"), 600, replace = T, prob = c(0.25, 0.25, 0.5)),
  Store = sample(seq(1:8), 600, replace = T), 
  Interviewer = sample(seq(1:10), 600, replace = T),
  Sale = sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), 600, replace = T, prob = c(0.25, 0.75)),
  Date = sample(seq(as.Date('2020/02/02'), as.Date('2020/02/14'), by="day"), 600, replace = T),
  Day = NA,
  Within.Period = NA
)

list1 <- list1[with(list1,
                    order(Region, Store, Interviewer, Sale, Date))]

list2 <- list1[with(list2,
                    order(Region, Store, Interviewer, Sale, Date))]

dates <- data.table(
  Region = c(rep(NA, 4), "A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C"),
  City = c(rep(NA, 8), 0, 0, 1, 1),
  Store = c(1, 1, 2, 2, rep(NA, 8)),
  Month = rep(c(1,2), 6),
  Sale.Date = as.Date(c("02.01", "03.02", "03.01", "04.02", "03.01", "04.02", "06.01", "07.02", "09.01", "10.02", "09.01", "10.02"), format = "%d.%m"),
  Day.1 = as.Date(c("01.01", "02.02", "02.01", "03.02", "02.01", "03.02", "05.01", "06.02", "08.01", "09.02", "08.01", "09.02"), format = "%d.%m"),
  Day.2 = as.Date(c(rep(NA, 2),"03.01", "04.02", "03.01", "04.02", "06.01", "07.02", "09.01", "10.02", "09.01", "10.02"), format = "%d.%m"),
  Day.3 = as.Date(c(rep(NA, 4), "04.01", "05.02", "07.01", "08.02", "10.01", "11.02", "10.01", "11.02"), format = "%d.%m"),
  Day.4 = as.Date(c(rep(NA, 6), "08.01", "09.02", "11.01", "12.02", "11.01", "12.02"), format = "%d.%m"),
  Day.5 = as.Date(c(rep(NA, 10), "12.01","13.02"), format = "%d.%m")
)

dates_melted <- melt(dates, id.vars = c("Region", "City", "Store", "Month", "Sale.Date"), variable.name = "Day", value.name = "Date", na.rm = TRUE)
´´´
```

At first, I tried to solve the problem by subsetting the data.tables and merge or left_join. Problem here is that I want to compare dates of different Regions and/or Stores. Furthermore, they are not disjoint and can overlap.

Secondly, i tried to provide the correct logical value for each condition via (here the 2nd condition):

```
dt_list1$Within.Period <- with(dt_list1, Store == "3" & ifelse(Sale == FALSE, Date %in% dt_dates_melted$Dates[dt_dates_melted$Region == "C" & dt_dates_melted$City == 1], Date %in% dt_dates_melted$Sale.Dates[dt_dates_melted$Region == "C" & dt_dates_melted$City == 1]))
´´´
```

As this would work for the specific cases, it does not work for the 1st (and also last) condition:

```
dt_list1$Within.Period <- with(dt_list1, Store %in% dt_dates_melted$Store & ifelse(Sale == FALSE, Date %in% dt_dates_melted$Dates[!is.na(dt_dates_melted$Store)], Date %in% dt_dates_melted$Sale.Dates[!is.na(dt_dates_melted$Store)]))

´´´
```

This would compare the dates of specific Stores with ALL remaining Store Dates of dt_dates_melted.

The second problem which would emerge by this kind of comparison is, that it would NOT provide the corresponding >Day< of dt_dates_melted, which is needed for the second question:

I would like to fill the >Day< column of dt_list1 and dt_list2 with their respective days of dt_listed_melted.

As this is my first question and I am relatively new to programming in R, I am looking forward to get some kind of help.

Finally, I should also mention, that the original data sets have got 50 columns and 70'000 rows with 20 Regions, 300 Stores and 200 Interviewers.

With best regards, 
Julian